# UML - Modelling of static imports used in Java

Tags: java, import, uml, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to model Javas static imports in UML? I.e.

```
import static com.myCompany.Globals.MY_GLOBAL_VALUE;
```

So that I only need to use `MY_GLOBAL_VALUE` instead of `Globals.MY_GLOBAL_VALUE`...

---

**EDIT:
maybe I should give a more precise example of what I want to achieve...**

Let's say I have modelled the following:
[image]

I have an abstract class (AContentProvider) with 2 protected members, which I want to be empty (“”) when initialized. As I don’t want to use “”-Strings inside the abstract class, I created the ConstantStrings class to hold all constant strings and also imported it to AContentProvider.
It now generates like this (Enterprise Architect):

```
package tools.integration.contentprovider;
import java.lang.String;
import tools.integration.util.ConstantStrings;

abstract class AContentProvider implements IContentProvider {

    protected String content = ConstantStrings.GENERAL_EMPTY_STRING;

    protected String origin = ConstantStrings.GENERAL_EMPTY_STRING;

    public abstract String getContent();

    public String getOrigin(){
        return "";
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin){
    }
}
```

But actually I wanted something like this:

```
package tools.integration.contentprovider;
import java.lang.String;
import static tools.integration.util.ConstantStrings.GENERAL_EMPTY_STRING;

abstract class AContentProvider implements IContentProvider {

    protected String content = GENERAL_EMPTY_STRING;

    protected String origin = GENERAL_EMPTY_STRING;

    public abstract String getContent();

    public String getOrigin(){
        return "";
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin){

    }
}
```

Prolly there is no way that EA is going to generate it like this, but that's not problem. I just want to know if there is a way to model this ... hope things are clearer now :)

Comment: There's no way to model imports at all in UML...

Comment: @immibis can you support your claim by an evidence? What about http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html#element-import

Comment: I already use the <<import>> functionality. Just thought it might be possible to extend it somehow :)

Comment: [uml-diagrams.org: UML Package Diagrams Notation](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html#element-import) says "_Element import is a directed relationship between an importing namespace and imported [packageable element](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html#packageable-element). It allows the element to be referenced using its name without a qualifier.._". So I guess that as long as the thing you're importing falls into the category packagable element you can draw the `<<import>>` relationship as usual. What kind of extension are you looking for?

Comment: I don't want to access the class in that package. That can be done with <<import>>. But rather i'd like to directly import a static member of that class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: So your `MY_GLOBAL_VALUE` is not [UML packagable element](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html#packageable-element)? Which UML diagrams are you after? Show some more code and what you have drawn so far (see also [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Comment: It should be possible to customize the code generator to produce exactly what you need. See http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/extending_uml_models/codetemplatesoverview.html for an entry point. By adding the `[enterprise-architect]` tag to your question you may attract some experts able to answer your question clearly. [UML Property](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/classifier.html) does not look like "_..named element that may be owned directly by a package.._" so it probably can not stand at the end of the `<<import>>` dependency. EA 11 does not seem to support it...

Comment: You mean something like this: http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1418987304 ?

Comment: Have you tried the other way around: write the code and then import it into EA?

Comment: @ThomasKilian: yes, this question is similiar. I now need to figure out, how to change the code generator (in case this is the only way). This would be a suitable solution.

Comment: @GeertBellekens yes I tried, but either I do something wrong, or it's not possible to put classes from different packages into the same diagram and see their relations then. I can only create a diagram for each package.

Comment: That would be another story than :-) I'm pretty sure you can do that but takes some effort. I'd rather prefer automation to create code which could do it anyway.

Comment: @Matthias why wouldn't it be possible to add classes from different packages into single diagram? EA doesn't have any restrictions regarding things like that. As soon as you put two elements on a diagram EA will automatically show all relations between those two elements (except when you explicitly hide the relations)

Comment: @GeertBellekens at least not when I do it with this example :(

Comment: @Matthias if EA doesn't show the relation that means the relation doesn't exist. You can easily verify the existence of the relation using the Traceability View. That might mean there's a bug in the reverse engineering process of EA. If so you better send in a bug report.